# Append pdf to itext pdf in memory within a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, pdf, itext

I am creating a system that dynamically creates a PDF using iText for Java from within a servlet using a **ByteArrayOutputStream**, and **PdfWriter**, to prevent filesystem usage.

I would like to be able to append some existing PDF file pages to the end of the dynamically created PDF once the dynamic content is complete.

I've looked at the example code to concatenate PDFs using iText, and they use **PdfCopy** to accomplish this. The big assumption for **PdfCopy** is that all files being concatenated exist on the file system.

Is it possible to concatenate the existing files to the end of the in memory PDF, that exists as a **ByteArrayOutputStream**?

In the meantime, I have used a temporary file for the initial dynamic document, but would like to remove that dependency if possible.

Thanks,

Allen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assuming that you can only create a `PdfReader` instance using a path to a file. This assumption is wrong. See [the API documentation](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#constructor_summary). If `baos` is your `ByteArrayOutputStream`, you could easily create your reader instance like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. I'll implement this shortly, hopefully tomorrow. Thanks Bruno.

Answer (score 1):

Having a list of `InputStream` (different documents) you can append them in an `OutputStream` in this way (based in [this](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=123)):

```
private void doMerge(List<InputStream> list, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws DocumentException, IOException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, outputStream);
    document.open();
    int n;
    for (InputStream in : list) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(in);
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            // loop over the pages in that document
            for (int page = 0; page < n; ) {
                copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
            }
            copy.freeReader(reader);
            reader.close();
        }
    }
    outputStream.flush();
    document.close();
    outputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: As mentioned many times before, this is *not* how one should concatenate PDFs. With `new Document()`, you create a document of which all the pages are size A4 in portrait. How do you know the size of each PdfImportedPage is also A4 in portrait? What if the original documents contains annotations? They will all be lost when using the combination of `PdfWriter` and `PdfImportedPage`. Please adapt your example so that it uses `PdfCopy` as indicated in the question.

Comment: I just provided the response based on the code I actually have, good to know new things ;-)

Comment: +1 Thanks! The resulting PDF is also more robust: instead of using Form XObjects for the imported pages, you now have real page dictionaries and content streams.